# How to execute functions properly in jquery

Tags: jquery, function

Im having difficulty getting a jquery function to behave as I would like.  I believe the hover handler is being registered multiple times, causing it to fire repeatedly, but I'm unsure how to do it properly.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
function hoverOptions(target)
{
 var option = target.children('.option');
 var tooltip = option.children('.tooltip');

 option
 .fadeToggle(150, function() { console.log('option'); })
 .hover(function() { console.log('tooltip'); });
};

$(document).on('hover', '#myElement', function()                
{      
 $(hoverOptions($(this)));
});
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle.com with your HTML markup and replicate the issue so we can test it also

Answer (score 0):

I think your are registering this event twice.

```
function hoverOptions(target)
{
 var option = target.children('.option');
 var tooltip = option.children('.tooltip');

 option
 .fadeToggle(150, function() {console.log('option');)} 
 .hover(function(){console.log('tooltip')});
};

$(document).on('hover', '#myElement', function()                
{
     hoverOptions($(this));
};
```

If you want to declare your method in the jQuery namespace:

```
$.hoverOptions = function(target){ //Your code }
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to fade two separate things.  Option (which is a trash icon), fades on when you mouse over #myElement.  If you mouse over the trash icon it fades in the tooltip of "delete".

Comment: declaring the method in the jQuery namespace is poor design. Put your functions in your own namespace, don't pollute someone else's. You never know when a collision will occur.

Comment: @jcolebrand Agreed. Skyros, Are you trying to fade out 'option' and fade in 'tooltip'?

Answer (score 0):

You are registering hover events when you appear to want to invoke them.

Also, you are delegating the event just for one element. Event delegation is only really a good idea where many elements are involved in the event.

It's not completely clear what you want, but I've taken a guess at this (note the reduced code).

```
//on hover to #myElement, fade toggle the .option child
$('#myElement').on('hover', function() {;
    $(this).children('.option').fadeToggle(150, function() {
        console.log('option');
    });
});

//on hover to .option elements, toggle the .tooltip child
$('.option').hover(function() { $(this).children('.tooltip').toggle(); });
```